# missing disk space in AIX

Tags: aix, disk-space-utilization

i have an AIX server.. where the partition supposed to have 39gb worth of space.. 
but when i do a df -k, it shows that i have used up almost 24gb of space...
but as i listed out everything under that mount point.. the size of the files does not worth that much of space.. so where did the space went missing to?

```
$ 
$ df -k
Filesystem    1024-blocks      Free %Used    Iused %Iused Mounted on
/dev/hd4           131072      4720   97%     1724    59% /
/dev/hd2          1703936    541252   69%    34662    22% /usr
/dev/hd9var        131072     76636   42%      484     3% /var
/dev/hd3          1048576   1045528    1%       94     1% /tmp
/dev/hd1          2097152   1361216   36%    16565     6% /home
/proc                   -         -    -         -     -  /proc
/dev/hd10opt       131072     46644   65%     1530    13% /opt
/dev/lvlos        3145728   2677572   15%     8528     2% /los
/dev/lvu01       16908288  10989512   36%    19273     1% /u01
/dev/lvu02       40894464  14807568   64%       12     1% /u02
$ pwd
/
$ cd /u02
$ pwd
/u02
$ ls -lRa
total 24
drwxrwxrwx   5 root     system          256 Oct 03 13:45 .
drwxr-xr-x  21 root     system         4096 Nov 11 14:55 ..
drwxrwxrwx   2 root     system          256 Oct 04 15:31 db_dump
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     system          256 Sep 24 2009  lost+found
drwxrwxr-x   2 oracle   oinstall       8192 Nov 16 07:07 oradata
./db_dump:
total 0
drwxrwxrwx   2 root     system          256 Oct 04 15:31 .
drwxrwxrwx   5 root     system          256 Oct 03 13:45 ..

./lost+found:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     system          256 Sep 24 2009  .
drwxrwxrwx   5 root     system          256 Oct 03 13:45 ..

./oradata:
total 1169688
drwxrwxr-x   2 oracle   oinstall       8192 Nov 16 07:07 .
drwxrwxrwx   5 root     system          256 Oct 03 13:45 ..
-rw-r-----   1 root     system         1994 Mar 01 2010  PJ_UAT_bkcrontab_without_gzip
-rw-r-----   1 root     system         2060 Mar 01 2010  PJ_UAT_crontab_with_gzip
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root     system    598843639 Nov 14 20:49 abmb_glos_uatlosdb_20110105_0200.dmp.gz
-rw-r-----   1 root     system          269 Mar 01 2010  alc_sizing.sh
-rw-r-----   1 oracle   oinstall        245 Nov 23 2009  import.parfile
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root     system           48 Mar 01 2010  pj_uat_gzip_dump_files.sh
$
```

any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

du only totals files that are linked into the filesystem tree.  Files that have been unlinked, but are still held open by processes still use disk space.  Some applications (including Oracle, which you appear to be using) use unlinked files for scratch space, since filesystem access is several times faster than swap, and the space is automatically reclaimed when the database is shut down.

Comment: I'd strongly suspect it is indeed unlinked files. To verify, either re-check with all the applications on the system not running, or use a too like lsof to look for unlinked files totaling the missing space. Depending on the version of lsof, it may either explicitly say unlinked or the partition mount point.